# compare every two people's movement in sql

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following attributes in one table in hive:

`PERSON_ID`, `DAY`, `ZONE`, `TIME`, `DWELL_TIME`

i need to know which person have similar movement in the same zone, day, time and dwell time of another person in the same table in hive

People who move at the same time in the same zone and stay in that zone for a similar duration then it should be considered as the same person.

Basically i am trying to eliminate double-sim users by identifying similar movement.

**Table:**

[image: table]

**Result:**

[image: result]

I am not sure how to write the code for this problem in hive, can someone help?

if you need more elaboration, let me know

thank you

Comment: How do you define a *movement*? Sample data and expected results would help clarifiying your question.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I have updated the problem

Comment: @GMB i have updated the problem

Comment: What if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @GMB we take the people who are repeatedly matching for at least 80% of the time. there are millions of records in the table, not just the one in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the list of ids for each set of data using:

```
select collect_list(ids) as all_ids, day_id, initial_time, final_time, zone_id
from t
group by day_id, initial_time, final_time, zone_id;
```

This may solve the problem that you want to solve.  You can join back to the table to add a column of *all* ids.

Comment: some people would be at the same zone in the same day but not exactly the same time, there would be a difference of 1-5 minutes between each person. so how can i take that into account in this case ? because this code will only work if two people have exactly the same timing, which is not the case 100% of the time. Also, thank you

Comment: @bash . . . That would be a different question.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61518553/6322645     .. this is the new question please take a look